# Передача модели в каждый action. Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, model

Чтобы не писать в каждом action о передаче данных из модели User
Как передавать данные в каждый action?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1. В экшенах обращаться к приватному методу контроллера. Такой подход используется при генерации CRUD с помощью GII.

```
/**
 * @param int $userId
 */
public function actionViewProfile($userId)
{
    $user = $this->getUser($userId);
    ...
}

/**
 * @param int $userId
 *
 * @return User
 * @throws \console\controllers\NotFoundHttpException
 */
private function getUser($userId)
{
    if (($model = User::findOne($userId)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('User not found');
    }
}
```

Также, контроллер можно наследовать не от контроллера yii, а от собственного, где данный метод сделать `protected` и позволить всем контроллерам иметь этот метод. Однако, наследование лучше заменить использованием [поведений](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/concept-behaviors.md) в нужных контроллерах.

Вариант 2. Запихнуть вызов приватного метода в `beforeAction` чтобы не дублировать код. Подходит под ситуации когда *всем* экшенам требуется пользователь.

```
/**
 * @var User
 */
private $_user;

/**
 * @param \yii\base\Action $action
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->_user = $this->getUser(Yii::$app->request->get('userId'));

    return true;
}
```

С учетом того что `beforeAction` прежде всего предназначен для определения того будет или не будет выполняться экшен я бы этот вариант не использовал.